# Symbolic link permission changes

Tags: permissions, symlink

I would like to change the symbolic permission[lrwxrwxrwx] to 755. I've used the command to try and change the permissions and it's not working.

```
$ chmod -R 755 symbolic link folder
```

Comment: I don't think you can change it. The permissions on a symbolic link don't matter, and are always displayed as 777. Only the permissions on the file it points to matters.

Comment: inside the files under symbolic folder shall we change it.please let me know.

Comment: what jw013 said stands, even for folders. You don't change the permissions of the link, you change the permissions of what the link points to.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `chmod -R 755 link folder` will not change the perms on the symlink itself but will change the perms on the folder pointed to and everything underneath.

Comment: please let me know if my understand is wrong.1) /home/stage/release/dds --> /home/stage/perm   2) perm folder having work,data,logs folders 3) I use the command to change inside the underneath folder of symlink folder but not changing.Anyway thanks for your prompt response.Really thankfull.

Comment: could you please tell me the command are take one example for better understand.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the permissions of a symbolic link. You could use `acl(5)` to change that. As an expmple you can use `setfacl --set u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x /path/to/filename` to change the ACL although that won't change the permissions of the *file*.